# Python df returning NaN instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import a csv file into python but the values won't show.

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None)

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time','x','y'])

print(df)
```

Output shows as:

```
time   x   y

0     NaN NaN NaN

1     NaN NaN NaN

2     NaN NaN NaN

3     NaN NaN NaN

4     NaN NaN NaN
..    ...  ..  ..
875   NaN NaN NaN
876   NaN NaN NaN
877   NaN NaN NaN
878   NaN NaN NaN
879   NaN NaN NaN
```

CSV file looks like:
[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtYKM.png)

I want to be able subtract time to find the difference. So far I've tried time_1 - time_0 but then it also returns NaN.

Can someone offer some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read a CSV file and store it into Dataframe, then `read_csv` should be able to do this.

You dont need the second line. I think you are using second line create the header names. You can do that while reading csv itself.

Here is how you can do it.

```
header_list = ['time','x','y']
my_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", names=header_list)

print(my_df)
```

Comment: That was the quickest fix ever... **facepalm**. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear it worked. Feel free to ask any queries/doubts. Also, please don't forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it helps.  :)

Answer (score 0):

pandas.read_csv() already returns a DataFrame. So you can do it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/test.csv', header=None, sep = ';')
df.columns = ['time','x','y']
```